# How to Get Simple Data From Cloud Firestore For Flutter App?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

When I Run getting following error. These are basic code for flutter into firebase.

**The following assertion was thrown building MyHomePage(dirty, state: MyHomePageState#b163a):
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': Failed assertion: line 235 pos 15: 'data != null': is not**

**Please, Can Anyone Help me How to Resolve This?**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  final FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
    name: 'vscodefirebase',
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
      googleAppID: 'xxx',
      gcmSenderID: 'xxx',
      apiKey: 'xxxx',
      projectID: 'vscodefirebase',
    ),
  );
  final Firestore firestore = Firestore(app: app);
  await firestore.settings(timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: true);

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Firebase',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('books').snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text('Loading...');
          return new ListView(
            children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              return new ListTile(
                title: new Text(document['title']),
                subtitle: new Text(document['author']),
              );
            }).toList(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Text widget with null text.

Here, you did not enter title property for MyHomePage

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Firebase',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

So this Text widget has null text value.

```
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
```

To solve this, declare MyHomePage like this:

```
MyHomePage(title: "My Home Page")
```

Comment: thank you for you awesome reply. 

But still i am getting below error.

[{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}

Comment: @fluttertalk mmm, I have never seen that error. May be flutter clean might fix it? If you open another stack overflow question, I might be able to help you there!